# Calling a middleware from within a middleware in NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have created some standard middleware with some logic, and depending on the logic I need to call some 3rd party middleware.

Middleware is added using app.use(), which is where I add my custom middleware.

Once in my middleware I no longer have access to app.use(), how do I call the middleware?

Here is some code:

Any ideas ?

```
const customerData = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log('Started');
    if (process.env.STORE_CUSTOMER_DATA === 'true') {

        // Here is some custom middleware that doesn't belong to me
        //
        // Returns a function (I confirmed it) ready to be called with res,req, next
        //
        let externalMiddlware = logger({
          custom:true
        });

// Do I return it ? Call it ? Trying everything and nothing seems to work

        externalMiddlware(req,res,next);  // ???
    } else {

      // DO not call external middleware, will break out of if and then call next()
    }
    console.log('Finished');
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

module.exports = customerData;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work but if you delegate the callback to this other externalMiddlware you should not call next() in customerData use this 3rd middleware

so have you try

```
const customerData = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log('Started');
    if (process.env.STORE_CUSTOMER_DATA === 'true') {
        let externalMiddlware = logger({
          custom:true
        });
        return externalMiddlware(req,res,next); 
    } else {
        return next(); // <= next moved
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

module.exports = customerData;
```