# How to dynamically skip express csurf based on form data?

Tags: node.js, forms, express, csrf, csrf-token

I have a third party who wants to send a form via POST to my website to preset some inputs.
A POST is also used to finalize the form and process data when all fields have been provided.

The form should be CSRF-protected when the user submits it and data is to be processed server-side but should skip CSRF token check when the third party initially sends some data.

What's a clean way to bypass CSRF verification based on the data sent to a specific route and HTTP verb/method when using csurf?

One way I see is to work around this by using different route endpoints, but is there a more direct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find you answer in here: [Calling a middleware from within a middleware in NodeJS/ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572752/calling-a-middleware-from-within-a-middleware-in-nodejs-expressjs). The thing is to implement a middleware which would call the csrf middleware in conditions match, or else directly call the next middleware with `next()`.

Example:

```
app.use('my-route', (req, res, next) => {
    if (condition) {
        return csrfMiddleware(req, res, next);
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

If you want to use this middleware for a specific verb, replace `app.use` with `app.<verb>`. For example, app.get is pretty much a middleware checking for *get* verb.

Comment: Thanks, I've also thought about this but find it rather convoluted and confusing because it implements one thing at different layers, and for this problem, just for one case. Sort of a sandwich with csurf in between.

Comment: Update: I actually ended up doing something like this now to get it done :-/

Comment: @Arc, have you found a alternative solution here? I'm trying to make a request in my express server inside a chrome extension but i have set a csrf protection on those routes.